# How do I use Solve[] for a variable number of equations?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to solve a large system of linear equations. The problem is that, based on user input, the number of equations will vary.

As a specific example, say I have two equations in two unknowns. I can write

```
Solve[{x+y==1&&2x+2y==3},{x,y}]
```

Is there a way that I can generalize the above solve for any number of equations and variables without having to explicitly type out everything? My equations and variables are stored in arrays.

Comment: It would be useful to have explicit examples of the arrays in which the eqns and vars are stored

Answer (score 3):

The syntax will depend on the form in which you store them. If, for example, you have

```
eqns = {x - y == 1, 2 x + 2 y == 3, 5*x - 3*y - z == 2}
vars = {x, y, z}
```

then you can do

```
Solve[eqns, vars]
(*
{{x -> 5/4, y -> 1/4, z -> 7/2}}
*)
```

(thanks to Mr.Wizard for reminding me of the correct syntax)

Comment: thanks acl. I spent a few hours trying to figure this out. To answer your questions, yes I'm new to mathematica.

Comment: @user what, a few hours and @@ never occured to you?? :) I agree it can be difficult to work out how to do simple things in mathematica in the beginning.

Comment: @acl, review my answer; if you agree that `And @@` is extraneous and you update your question accordingly, I will delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Acl wrote, you can use `LinearSolve`:

I am borrowing Acl data

```
Remove["Global`*"];
eqns = {x - y == 1, 2 x + 2 y == 3, 5*x - 3*y - z == 2}
vars = {x, y, z}

A = CoefficientArrays[eqns, vars];
sol = LinearSolve[A[[2]], -A[[1]]]
```

which gives

```
{5/4, 1/4, 7/2}

In[135]:= Thread[vars->sol]
Out[135]= {x->5/4,y->1/4,z->7/2}
```